av1_vaapi ffmpeg throws error on last frame of video
I've been using ffmpeg and vaapi to transcode video files, it has been working great except for one group of video which has been throwing the error
[vf#0:0 @ 0x5d37f5dd6dc0] Reconfiguring filter graph because video parameters changed to yuv420p(tv, smpte170m), 720x480
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_hwupload_1' and the filter 'auto_scale_1'
[vf#0:0 @ 0x5d37f5dd6dc0] Error reinitializing filters!
[vf#0:0 @ 0x5d37f5dd6dc0] Task finished with error code: -38 (Function not implemented)
[vf#0:0 @ 0x5d37f5dd6dc0] Terminating thread with return code -38 (Function not implemented)
given the command ffmpeg -i A1_t00.mkv -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD129 -vf 'format=nv12,hwupload' -c:v av1_vaapi A1_t002.mp4
I'm using an arc a380 card and am running in a docker container in a proxmox lxc several other files work just fine. If there is a way to completely ignore this error or resolve it that would be great. the file generated also plays fine even though an error is thrown
